# How to convert Bstr to Platform::String?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, winrt-component

Now I am doing a Windows Metro App job, and I am developing a C++ component to get the input method's candidate List.

An issue occurs at the last step to output the result list. I can get each member of the candidate list, but the type is the "Bstr", to get them in the Metro App, I have to convert them into the type of "Platform::String".

How to convert Bstr to Platform::String?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: A `BSTR` is a pointer to a nullterminated UTF-16 encoded string, with a 16-bit (I think it was) string length preceding the character pointed to. Depending on the encoding of a `Platform::String` you may have to do some conversion. Using the C++ standard library that would be via `std::codecvt`.

Answer (score 1):

The Platform::String constructor overloads make this very easy:

```
BSTR comstr = SysAllocString(L"Hello world");
auto wrtstr = ref new Platform::String(comstr);
```

To be perfectly complete, both BSTR and a WinRT string can contain an embedded 0.  If you want to handle that corner case then:

```
BSTR comstr = SysAllocStringLen(L"Hello\0world", 11);
auto wrtstr = ref new Platform::String(comstr, SysStringLen(comstr2));
```

Comment: Are you sure it is safe to cast `wchar_t*` to `char16_t*`? Both (`wchar_t` and `char16_t`)types are different internal types, not just typedefs of another. I couldn't find any reference stating that a cast would be safe.

Comment: There are no casts in these tested code snippets.  Makes it pretty hard to figure out what you might be talking about.  char16_t was necessary for Unix, it is irrelevant on Windows.  There's only one kind of utf-16 encoding.

Comment: Maybe I'm totally wrong here, but if you look at my answer and the links to the MSDN I posted it might become more clear what I mean. `BSTR` is `wchar*` while `Platform::String` awaits a `char16*`. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228149.aspx) and [cppreference.com`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) both character types represent UTF-16 characters, yet are distinct types. I just want to know whether casting between these types is safe as the internal binary representation of both types might be different (e.g. different complement).

Comment: As I said, there is no casting here and the difference is irrelevant.  Most visible by the platform.winmd metadata file *declaring* the constructor with const wchar_t*, the one the compiler uses and IntelliSense shows, and the *implementation* in vccorlib.h file using const char16_t*.  The metadata definition predates Microsoft actually implemented char16_t.

Comment: So the `char16*` is just saying to pass a UTF-16 string? I'm fine with that. Maybe sometime someone adjusts the MSDN page to avoid such a confusion.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN ([[1]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069(v=vs.85).aspx),[[2]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg269344(v=exchg.10).aspx)) we have this definitions:

```
#if !defined(_NATIVE_WCHAR_T_DEFINED)
typedef unsigned short WCHAR;
#else
typedef wchar_t WCHAR;
#endif
typedef WCHAR OLECHAR;
typedef OLECHAR* BSTR;
```

So `BSTR` is of type `wchar_t*` or `unsigned short*`, or a null terminated 16-bit string.

From what I see from the documentation of [`Platform::String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en_us/library/hh825856.aspx) the constructor accepts a null-terminated 16-bit string as `const char16*`

<s>While `char16` is guaranteed represent UTF16, `wchar` is not.</s>

***UPDATE:*** As [`Cheers and hth. - Alf`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464581/cheers-and-hth-alf) pointed out the line above isn't true for Windows/MSVC. I couldn't find any information on whether it is safe to cast between both types in this case. Since both `wchar_t` and `char16_t` are different integrated types I would still recommend to use `std::codecvt` to avoid problems.

So you should use [`std::codecvt`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt)  to convert from `wchar_t*` to `char16_t*` and pass the result to the constructor of your `Platform::String`.

Comment: "While char16 is guaranteed represent UTF16, wchar is not.". That's incorrect: this is in Windows.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thanks for pointing it out. I updated my answer.